# Makefile でサブディレクトリに同じターゲットを実行する方法

Tags: makefile

```
.
|--- Makefile
|--- a
|    |--- Makefile
|
|--- b
     |--- Makefile
```

という構成で

```
subdirs := a b

all: $(subdirs)

$(subdirs):
  make -C $@
```

というトップのMakefileをかいて 
make とうったら各ディレクトリで make を実行することはできるんですが

トップで make test や make clean とうったら各ディレクトリで
同じコマンドを実行できるようにする方法はないでしょうか

GNU Make 4.2.1 です

Comment: GNU make には `MAKECMDGOALS` という変数がありますので `make -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)` としておいて、`test clean: $(subdirs)` を追加するなどしておくと良いかと思います。

Comment: できました！　ありがとうございます！

Comment: 回答欄に回答を書かずにコメントに回答を書く人、何なの…。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU make には `MAKECMDGOALS` という変数がありますので `make -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)` としておいて、`test clean: $(subdirs)` を追加するなどしておくと良いかと思います。

---

*この投稿は [@metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/62152/makefile-%e3%81%a7%e3%82%b5%e3%83%96%e3%83%87%e3%82%a3%e3%83%ac%e3%82%af%e3%83%88%e3%83%aa%e3%81%ab%e5%90%8c%e3%81%98%e3%82%bf%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b2%e3%83%83%e3%83%88%e3%82%92%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95#comment67893_62152) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*